# Tkinter clipboard errors

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically what I'm trying to do is change whatever I copy into what I copied but it's all uppercase. Whenever I try to run the following program it crashes.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

prev_clip = root.clipboard_get()

while True:
    prev_clip = root.clipboard_get()
    root.clipboard_append(prev_clip.upper())

root.mainloop()
```

If it's impossible to do what I want this way, then tell me how I can do it. It would be preferred if I could do it this way, though.

Edit: This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[file location of the program]",     line 5, in <module>
    prev_clip = root.clipboard_get()
  File     "[file location of program]",     line 652, in clipboard_get
    return self.tk.call(('clipboard', 'get') + self._options(kw))
_tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? Does the program quit unexpectedly? Does it give any errors?

Comment: Yes, it does give errors. Sorry, I should have specified it in the question.

Comment: it doesn't work for me on Linux because `while True` doesn't run `mainloop()` and `tkinter` doesn't get text from clipboard. If I use `after()` to create loop then it get the same uppercase text from clipboad again and again and again - so it waste time on converting to uppercase already converted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED AFTER DOING MORE THAN MY INITIAL EXPERIMENTS:
I am not sure what you are trying to do, but the error is just what the message says: there is nothing in the clipboard, not even an empty string.  To prevent this, either use a try-except block or append a empty string with `root.clipboard_append('')` (see second code example).

If this were fixed, your infinite loop (`while True:`) would double the length of the clipboard text each loop until you got a different crash.

```
from tkinter import *
r = Tk()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('abc ')
for i in range(5):
    clip = r.clipboard_get()
    print(clip)
    r.clipboard_append(clip.upper())
```

prints

```
abc 
abc ABC 
abc ABC ABC ABC 
abc ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC 
abc ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC
```

This is surely not what you want.

Perhaps what you want is a function triggered by the user entering a new selection into the clipboard.  The function would clear the clipboard before appending the new version (as suggested by T. Kropalis).  Unfortunately, there is not, as far as I know, a CLIPBOARD-CHANGED event accessible via tkiter.

One thought I had was to bind the function to ^X and ^C in such a way that the function would be called after the Cut or Copy operation.  I tried and failed and am not sure it is possible.

Another is to choose other keys to mean 'Copy and uppercase' and 'Cut and uppercase'.  The function would then have to trigger the Cut or Copy operation to change the clipboard before uppercasing it, or directly Cut or Copy the current selection.  I believe the latter could be done.

A third option is a background loop to modify the clipboard.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

delay = 30  # milliseconds

def upper():
    clip = root.clipboard_get()
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(clip.upper())
    root.after(delay, upper)

tex = Text(root)
tex.pack()
tex.insert('insert', 'Some starting text\n')

root.clipboard_append('')  # Avoid "CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist" error.
root.after(delay, upper)
root.mainloop()
```

An improved version of `upper` might compare the current contents to the a saved copy of the previous contents (after uppercased) and only change the clipboard if the contents changed.

Comment: This helped. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found a way to resolve it. See if **this** helps you out

```
from Tkinter import Tk  

r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append(yourText)
r.destroy()
```